# Changing Python easy_install's default include path

Tags: python, macos, clang, setuptools, easy-install

Question about Python's setuptools.  I just did a fresh install of Mac OS 10.8 and installed the official Python 2.7.3 package.  When installing the binary module `py-bcrypt` (or any other binary module for that matter), I get the following error:

```
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:17:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Running `sudo easy_install --verbose py-bcrypt` shows the following call to CLang:

```
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/bcrypt/bcrypt_python.o
```

...which is fine except for this part:

```
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

Because `Python.h` is actually stored in the *non*-System Library here: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h`

So to finally get to the point: **How do you change the default include path used by setuptools?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, doing this in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` would solve the issue:

```bsh
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/you_name_it/include/python2.7
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/you_name_it/include/python2.7
```

It enabled `gcc` to find other headers you need, but I'm not sure whether it works for `clang`.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea how to actually do this, but I found a workaround.  Installing XCode's Command Line Tools (Preferences -> Download -> Command Line Tools) put Python headers in the right place.